# 3D primitive (303 NON_MANIFOLD_CASE) error

Tags: primitive, 3d-model

I need some help understanding and fixing the challenge with this 3D model please [-> [citjsnClean_cput3d_25m-str_solid.json](https://github.com/AdrianKriger/osm_LoD1_3DCityModel/blob/main/village_campus/extra/citjsnClean_cput3d_25m-str_solid.json)]

If I parse the file through [val3dity](http://geovalidation.bk.tudelft.nl/val3dity/) and check the 3D primitives; my concern is the [303 NON_MANIFOLD_CASE](https://val3dity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors/#non-manifold-case) error. `Make sure to select **Validation options** and set Snap tolerance to 0.0001`

If I look at the model (say: [CityJSON ninja](https://ninja.cityjson.org/)) and try to find which features are creating the issue it becomes clear these are objects that are connected *---that share vertices and edges*.

a) Are the shell surfaces oriented consistently? Do their Normals point outward? *---Am I fixing the right problem?*
b) Is there a *---hidden---* polygon (a duplicate surface where the individual models touch) that I am unaware of / can't see?
c) How will this error affect the usability of the model? What can I now NOT do with the model?